# The Density Of The Real And Rationals

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to get better understanding of the density property of the real numbers and the rational.

As for the rational if we take for example $\frac{1}{100} $ and $\frac{1}{101}$ which number can we put between them? $\frac{1}{1001} $?

As for the real numbers, if we have $0.1$ and $0.2$ we can say that $0.10,0.101...$ are between them and so on? if so, the cardinality of any two numbers $|a-b|<1$ is infinite or $\aleph_0$?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question the easiest answer is $\frac{\frac{1}{100}+\frac{1}{101}}{2}$. $\frac{1}{1001}$ won't work since it's smaller then both of them.

$0.10=0.1$ so it's not strictly between $0.1$ and $0.2$.

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the cardinality of any two numbers $|a-b|$. If you are asking about $|(a,b)|=|\{x;a<x<b\}$ than if we are looking at real numbers the cardinality of that set for any $a<b$ is always uncountably infinite.

Answer (score 1):

If $\,\dfrac ab<\dfrac cd$ are any two rational numbers, $\,\dfrac{a+c}{b+d}\,$  is between them (I suppose $b,d>0$).

As for the real numbers, I suppose you mean the *irrational* numbers. If $x<y$, there is a decimal approximation $\,x_\text{dec}\,$ of $x$ from above and a decimal approximation $\,y_\text{dec}\,$ of $y$ from below such that:
$$x<x_\text{dec}<y_\text{dec}<y.$$

Comment: That first claim seems wrong. Check $\frac{2}{3}<\frac{2001}{3000}$ but $\frac{2}{3}\not <\frac{5}{5001}$

Comment: Oops! Thanlks for pointing the typo!

Comment: @Bernard so basically the real numbers are rational and irrational numbers one after the other?  like the Dirichlet function?

Comment: Not one after another, since $\mathbf R$ is not denumerable. They're inextricably mixed. Any interval (as small as you wish) actually contains both an infinity of rational numbers and an infinity of irrational numbers. Let me add that, in a certain sense, there are many more irrational numbers than rational numbers.